# Custom Post Type Object - Undefined Variables

Tags: plugin-development, errors, variables

I am writing a plugin that uses a class in order to generate custom post types. I am using PHPStorm and it is reporting that some variables are undefined.

For Example...

```
class Custom_Post_Type {
        public $post_type_name;
        public $post_type_args;
        public $post_type_labels;

        /** Constructor */
        public function __construct( $name, $args = array(), $labels = array() ) {

            // Set Variables
            $this->$post_type_name      = strtolower( str_replace( ' ','_', $name) );
            $this->$post_type_args      = $args;
            $this->$post_type_lables    = $labels;
```

PHPStorm is reporting that `$post_type_name`, `$post_type_args`, and `$post_type_labels` are undefined and thus are errors.

I am also getting the same error with this section of code too:

```
public function add_taxonomy( $name, $args = array(), $labels = array() ) {

if( ! empty( $name ) ) {

    // Get Post Name
    $post_type_name = $this->post_type_name;

    // Taxonomy Properties
    $taxonomy_name   = strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '_', $name ) );
    $taxonomy_labels = $labels;
    $taxonomy_args   = $args;

    if( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy_name ) ) {

        // Capitalize words and make them plural
        $name   = ucwords( str_replace( '_', ' ', $this->post_type_name ) );
        $plural = self::pluralize( $name );

        // Set labels with some defaults and merge in overrides
        $labels = array_merge(

            // Defaults
            array(
                'name'               => _x( $plural, 'Post Type General Name' ),
                'singular_name'      => _x( $name, 'Post Type Singular Name' ),
                'search_items'       => __( 'Search', $plural ),
                'parent_item'        => __( 'Parent ' . $name ),
                'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent ' . $name . ':' ),
                'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit' . $name ),
                'update_item'        => __( 'Update' . $name ),
                'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New' . $name ),
                'new_item_name'      => __( 'New' . $name . ' Name' ),
                'menu_name'          => __( $name ),
            ),

            // Overrides
            $taxonomy_labels
        );

        // Set default arguments and merge in overrides
        $args = array_merge(

            // Default Values
            array(
                'label'             => $plural,
                'labels'            => $labels,
                'public'            => true,
                'show_ui'           => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                '_builtin'          => false,
            ),

            // Overrides
            $taxonomy_args
        );

        // Create Taxonomy and Add it to the Post Type
        add_action( 'init',
            function() use( $taxonomy_name, $post_type_name ) {
                register_taxonomy( $taxonomy_name, $post_type_name, $args );
            }
        );

        } else {

            // Add Already-Existing Taxonomy to Post Type
            add_action( 'init',
                function() use( $taxonomy_name, $post_type_name ) {
                    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $taxonomy_name, $post_type_name );
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

PHPStorm is telling me that `$args` in the `register_taxonomy()` statement is also not defined.

My question is are these variables actually undefined and this this plugin will blow up in my face when I enable it for testing or is it just a PHPStorm bug/quirk? Obviously this is not something I can test right away but I want to clear these errors before going any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some minor confusion here and syntax issues.

**Bad:** You're including the `$` sign when setting property values.

```
// Set Variables
$this->$post_type_name      = strtolower( str_replace( ' ','_', $name) );
$this->$post_type_args      = $args;
$this->$post_type_lables    = $labels;
```

**Good:** Omit the `$` once you've declared them.

```
// Set Variables
$this->post_type_name      = strtolower( str_replace( ' ','_', $name) );
$this->post_type_args      = $args;
$this->post_type_lables    = $labels;
```

**Good:** This is good too, you have this right.

```
public $post_type_name;
public $post_type_args;
public $post_type_labels;
```

---

Regarding `$args`. It's difficult to tell where the second snippet fits in exactly, but assuming it's in the constructor, I'm not seeing an `$args` variable within the context of your closure. You'll need to `use($args)` if that variable is from the outer scope.

```
add_action( 'init',
    function() use( $taxonomy_name, $post_type_name, $args ) {
        register_taxonomy( $taxonomy_name, $post_type_name, $args );
    }
);
```

---

See also: [PHP closures, inheriting variables from parent scope](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-165)

Comment: It's in a separate function. I'm updating the question with the full function now.

Comment: The full method has been added to the original question

Comment: Actually, I found my problem. I missed injecting it in the `use()` function.